# Getting selected date from calendar date picker

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, datepicker

I need help with getting the selected date from calendar date picker. Currently I can select the date(from...to...) and place it into textbox. But I cannot get the value to put into PHP variable.

```
<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 3,
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                }
            });
            $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 3,
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                }
            });


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


        <label for="from">From</label>
        <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />


        <label for="to">to</label>
        <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />

</body>
```

Comment: put it in form after submit you will get the value in $_POST[form] and   $_POST[to].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't got a form to submit. You should create a form first, like so:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">

    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />


    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit dates">
</form>
```

And on the server side, if you're submitting the form via POST (as in the example above), you can obtain the dates from the PHP $_POST variable:

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
```

Answer (score 1):

On submitting that form you can get that from that name of the input which you have pointed for the date. (i.e) `$_POST['from']` and `$_POST['to']`.

Comment: while you submit your form, you can check the post value by using print_r($_POST);

Comment: f--k. he asked for date value only. :)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value in PHP you can do it by two way.
1> Either by placing form and a submit button and get those value in POST.
2> Second one is by AJAX call in blur events of the input box.